# How do I extend a host object (e.g. Error) in TypeScript

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I would like to extend the host object `Error` to a custom `UploadError` class. The following example fails when I compile:

```
class UploadError extends Error {
    constructor(message: string, private code: number) {
        super(message);
    }

    getCode(): number {
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

When I run the TypeScript compiler `tsc` I get the following error:

```
UploadError.ts(1,0): A export class may only extend other classes, Error is an interface.
```

It seems `Error` is defined as an interface. If anyone knows what the name of the implementation is it would make me very happy :-)

## Update: I want to use Typescripts inheritance not prototypical inheritance like I currently employ to hack around this:

```
function UploadError (message: string, code: number) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
}

UploadError.prototype = new Error();

UploadError.prototype.constructor = UploadError;

UploadError.prototype.getCode = (): number => {
    return this.code;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the following approach works:

```
declare class ErrorClass implements Error {
    public name: string;
    public message: string;
    constructor(message?: string);
}
var ErrorClass = Error;

class MyError extends ErrorClass {
    public name = "MyError";
    constructor (public message?: string) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

The generated script looks like:

```
var ErrorClass = Error;
var MyError = (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyError, _super);
    function MyError(message) {
        _super.call(this, message);
        this.message = message;
        this.name = "MyError";
    }
    return MyError;
})(ErrorClass);
```

Comment: For me, this generates the compile error: error TS2000: Duplicate identifier 'ErrorClass'.

Answer (score 34):

#### Update for TypeScript 1.6:

It's now possible to directly extend from the `Error` class, the code in my original answer still works, but there's no longer a need for the `export declare class Error`.

#### Original answer:

Most of the answers here don't meet my requirements. The originally accepted answer doesn't compile anymore since 0.9.5 with a duplicate identifier exception. And non of them really have a stack trace (a JavaScript issue, not TypeScript).

For me a more elegant solution is:

```
module YourModule {
    export declare class Error {
        public name: string;
        public message: string;
        public stack: string;
        constructor(message?: string);
    }

    export class Exception extends Error {

        constructor(public message: string) {
            super(message);
            this.name = 'Exception';
            this.message = message;
            this.stack = (<any>new Error()).stack;
        }
        toString() {
            return this.name + ': ' + this.message;
        }
    }
}
```

What you can do with it:

- `new Exception("msg") instanceof Error == true`
- `class SpecificException extends Exception`
- `catch (e) { console.log(e.stack); }`

**The only limitation I found was that you have to declare it in a module, and cannot make them global.** For me this isn't an issue since I think a module helps in structuring, and they are there in any application I make.

One improvement you could make is strip your custom code from the stack trace, personally I think stacktraces are only for the eyes of developers, and they know where to look, so it's no big deal for me.

Comment: I think you can safely omit toString()

Comment: Is there any reason you'd want to omit it though? I personally like the style "SpecificException: ExceptionMessage" format it provides.

Comment: Could you please put more details under "Update for TypeScript 1.6:"? A code example would be really helpful.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner I'd recommend using the answer by @Dimitry nowadays. As for the update on 1.6, it's literally the same code as in the answer, you just remove the `export declare class Error { … }` clause.

Answer (score 26):

pay attention on the new changes in Typescript 2.1 - [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work)

So you can extend the Error class but, as a recommendation, you need manually adjust the prototype immediately after any super(...) calls:

```
class FooError extends Error {
    constructor(m: string) {
        super(m);

        // Set the prototype explicitly.
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, FooError.prototype);
    }

    sayHello() {
        return "hello " + this.message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

## Update

TypeScript 1.6 is bringing the ability to extend native types, so when this lands you should be able to use

```
class UploadError extends Error {
    //... calls to super and all that jazz
}
```

## Original Answer

You can implement the error interface in TypeScript, but this won't give you access to `super` as you aren't using inheritance:

```
class UploadError implements Error {
    public name = "CustomError";

    constructor (public message: string, private code: number){

    }
}

throw new UploadError ("Something went wrong!", 123);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible to extend `Error` class version 1.6. See pull request *Allow expressions in class extends clauses* https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3516 and issue *Can not extend built in types* https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1168

Note that `tsc` won't complain anymore but your editor/IDE will until it gets updated.

Comment: Note that this will no longer work in TypeScript 2.1: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work

Answer (score 2):

Extending interfaces is a breaking change documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work).

Solution: change manually prototype in your constructor.

```
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(m: string) {
        super(m);

        // Set the prototype explicitly. If you skip this, iinstanceof will not work :-(
        (<any>this).__proto__ = MyError.prototype;
    }
}

console.log("Instance of works now: "+(new MyError("my error") instanceof MyError));
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me on Node.js 6.9.4. Interestingly, the recommended solution from the linked TypeScript changelog with `Object.setPrototype` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prototype to add functions and attributes:

```
interface Error {
   code: number;
   getCode(): number;
}   

Error.prototype.code = 1;

Error.prototype.getCode = function () {
    return this.code;
}  
var myError = new Error();
console.log("Code: " + myError.getCode());
```

When run with `node.js`, this produces the following output:

```
Code: 1
```

Error is defined in `lib.d.ts` as follows:

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
}

declare var Error: {
    new (message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    prototype: Error;
}
```

Other than that, I see only the obvious solution to define your own interface that extends `Error`:

```
interface MyErrorInterface extends Error {       
    code: number;       
    getCode(): number;    
}       
class MyError implements MyErrorInterface {      
    code : number;      
    name : string;      
    message : string;
    constructor(code: number, name? : string, message? : string) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
    }   
    getCode(): number {
        return this.code;
    }   
}   

var myError = new MyError(1);
console.log("Code: " + myError.getCode());
```

Comment: That is what I currently have in place. But I didn't switch to TypeScript so I can still do inheritance myself.

Comment: I've added my current hack around this in the main post (since SO doesn't allow Markdown in comment #fail).

Comment: @MarijnHuizendveld Since Error is an interface I'm afraid there is no other way to do this that I'm aware of.

Comment: see my previous update. That code is working, however, I'd like a solution that is more TypeScript niceness and less JavaScript-ish...

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer has been accepted, and the solution is definitely impressive, but I really don't want that amount of code in my projects just for an exception.

Until TypeScript gets proper exceptions at the language-level somehow, with Error being so cumbersome to extend, I'm now using the following very simple solution:

```
class MyError {
    constructor(error: Error) {
        error.name = this['constructor'].name;
        error['type'] = this; // for type-checking in exception-handlers

        return error;
    }
}

throw new MyError(new Error('aw snap!'));
```

Now, my error-types are really classes - you can extend them, and you will see the correct class-name on the console when an unhandled Error is thrown; but my Error objects are not instances of those classes: the constructor does *not* return an instance of MyError, it just applies it's own name to the Error instance you pass to it.

This also provides a simple work-around for the issue of Error producing it's stack-trace at the point where you construct it, rather than at the point where you throw it - since the constructor signature forces you to construct a "real" Error instance.

If you need to check the type of exception in your exception-handler, grab the `['type']` property and compare it using `instanceof`:

```
try {
    // something throws new MyError(new Error('aw snap!'))
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error['type'] instanceof MyError); // => true
}
```

It's not ideal, but it's simple and it works.

Be aware that, if you extend MyError, you will need to implement the constructor every time and add `return super(...)`, since the default constructor generated by TypeScript does not expect constructors that use the return-statement. It does allow them though.

Answer (score 1):

Ron Buckton's solution worked for me when using TypeScript 0.8.3, but it does not compile in TypeScript 0.9.5. TypeScript generate compilation error: **Duplicate identifier 'ErrorClass'.** I have changed the code to make it work again:

```
declare class ErrorClass {
    public name: string;
    public message: string;
    constructor(message?: string);
}

// Move following line to a JavaScript
// (not TypeScript) file. 
// var ErrorClass = Error;

class MyError extends ErrorClass {
    public name = "MyError";
    constructor (public message?: string) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. Is not nice, but working as well... using eval() JS function to ignore TypeScript check.

```
declare class ErrorClass implements Error {
    public name: string;
    public message: string;
    constructor(message?: string);
}
eval('ErrorClass = Error');

export = Exception;
class Exception extends ErrorClass implements Error { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using TypeScript 1.8 but this may work for earlier versions:

```
class MyError extends Error {

  static name: string;

  constructor(public message?: string, public extra?: number) {
    super(message);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, MyError);
    this.name = (this as any).constructor.name; // OR (<any>this).constructor.name;
  }

};
```

Note that you must have the `node` typings installed in order to use `Error.captureStackTrace`.