# "Instanceof" not working properly

Tags: node.js, custom-exceptions

I don't know what wrong with this, but `instanceof` doesn't seem to work.

AppError.ts

```
class AppError extends Error {
    public statusCode;

    constructor(message, statusCode) {
      super(message);

      this.name = this.constructor.name;

      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

      this.statusCode = statusCode || 500;
    }
}

export default AppError;
```

BadRequestError.ts

```
import AppError from "./AppError";

class BadRequestError extends AppError {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(message || "Client sent a bad request", 400);
    }
}

export default BadRequestError;
```

handler.ts

```
try {
    throw new BadRequestError();
} catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof AppError) {
        responseCallback(err.statusCode, err.message, callback);
    } else {
        responseCallback(500, "Internal Server Error", callback);
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

> Status Code: 400
>
> Message: Client sent a bad request

Actual Result:

> Status Code: 500
>
> Message: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved!

Added this line to `BadRequestError` class.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, BadRequestError.prototype);
```

New `BadRequestError`:

```
import AppError from "./AppError";

class BadRequestError extends AppError {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(message || "Client sent a bad request", 400);

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, BadRequestError.prototype);
    }
}

export default BadRequestError;
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429145/8504830

Comment: Which version of TypeScript do you use?