# Losing instance of a class while using next to pass error in express.js

Tags: javascript, express, class, error-handling

I am trying to create custom errors for better reporting on my API. I am using a custom class called `ValidationError`. I create a new object of this class and `throw` it in `try` block. Thus, the object now comes into the `catch` class.

```
try{
   throw new ValidationError('Balance is insufficient')
}catch(err){
   console.log(err instanceof ValidationError) // returns true
   next(err)
}
```

So far everything is working fine. `next(err)` sends the control to this function in `app.js`

```
app.use((err , req , res , next)=>{
    console.log(err , err instanceof ValidationError)
    if(err instanceof ValidationError) return res.status(400).json({err : err.message})
    res.status(500).json({err : "Something went wrong. Internal error"})
})
```

Here this is the result of the `console.log` :

```
ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: Balance is insufficient
    at C:\Users\ganes\Documents\Software\DFinSerT\Tradilearn\backend\core\Routes\transactions.js:51:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errors: []
} false
```

As you can see, `err` has the same message so, I assume, it is the same object, but now it is no more an instance of `ValidationError`.

However, if I `reject()` an object of Validation error from a custom Promise, The control is not reaching the `catch` block of the route where the promise was called from. Instead it is directly going to the `app.use` error handler and this is the output.

```
ValidationError: Stock does not exists
    at C:\Users\ganes\Documents\Software\DFinSerT\Tradilearn\backend\core\Utils\Validators\stocks.js:11:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) true
```

This is the class definition

```
module.exports = class ValidationError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
      super(message);
      this.name = this.constructor.name;

      Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ValidationError.prototype);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, when the validation error is created from a Promise, it does not lose the instance. But when called from `catch` block using `next()` it loses the instance. Can someone please explain this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ValidationError.prototype);`? That will be done automatically for you.

Comment: I assume `SequelizeValidationError` is your class too? What is its definition? It looks like you're using that, not `ValidationError`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder was trying to debug and came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626231/custom-error-class-in-typescript. Thus, I just tried it

Comment: Ah. Yes. VScode auto imported the wrong class

Comment: (Re setting the prototype: That question is showing a change **TypeScript** made. You don't want to do that.) The auto-import thing is one of the several reasons not to use default exports. :-) Glad that solved it!