# What would an interface to describe an array of ASP.NET Modelstate look like in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have modelstate looking like this:

```
 var ModelState = {
    "model.StartDate": [ "The Start Date field is required." ],
    "model.EndDate": [ "The End Date field is required." ]
 }
```

I am then using this script to put this into an array:

```
var errors = [];
Object.keys(ModelState).forEach(function (key) {
   errors.push.apply(errors, ModelState[key]);
});
```

Can someone help me by telling me what the Typescript definition for errors would be.  I realize it will be an array but how can I represent the contents?

Comment: can you describe your problem a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom JS errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915412/how-do-i-extend-a-host-object-e-g-error-in-typescript) to define an error or if you want to use some type from C# you can use [this tool](http://type.litesolutions.net/) to transform C# types into TypeScript types.