# Globally Import in ionic framework angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using ionic framework and I've noticed that on a lot of my pages i'm using the same modules.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Then I have to set them in my constructor on each page.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http, private storage: Storage)
```

Is there a better way to auto include these on all my pages? Or is what I'm doing the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to auto include these on all my pages?

I'm afraid there is not. You could create a `BasePage` component where you can add all the imports and then in the rest of the pages you would need to import that `BasePage` to inherit the properties, but I guess it would be pretty much the same (this solution would make sense if you have a lot of imports in all the pages, or some repeated code/methods used  by all the pages; in that scenario you could place that code in the `BasePage` and use it in every other page).

Just in case if you want to take a look at how that could be done, please take a look at **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029212/typescript-and-multiple-classes/43030491#43030491)**

**So, if you are only including a *few* imports and properties in the constructor, what you're doing is the best solution.**