# Ionic 2 toast doesn't close on page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I use toast but if I have 2+ toasts open at the same time the toasts wont close.

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'İnternet bağlantınızda veya sunucuda sorun olabilir.',
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
});
toast.present();
```

Comment: Show your whole .ts page please. I think you created infinitive toast. I tested in my project with 2+ tab at a same time and they actually dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to your toast, and call `dismiss()` on it before presenting it. This solution will keep you from having more than one `Toast` presented at a time.

A solution I like to use myself is to handle all `Toast` interaction in a service. And inject that service in to whatever component/page/service you need it in.

**ToastService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ToastService{
    toast: Toast = null;

    constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController){ }

    presentToast(text:string):void{
        let toastData = {
            message: text,
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'top'
        }

        this.showToast(toastData);
    }

    presentClosableToast(text:string):void{
        let toastData = {
            message: text,
            showCloseButton: true,
            closeButtonText: 'X',
            position: 'top' 
        };

        this.showToast(toastData);
    }

    private showToast(data:any):void{
        this.toast ? this.toast.dismiss() : false;
        this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create(data);
        this.toast.present();
    }
}
```

Comment: Services shouldn't be used for UI interaction. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030491/2493235) for an alternative solution.